# What are at-rules in CSS and what is the "at" used for

Tags: css

In CSS there are at-rules that do different things, but with them I have seen the **@** symbol used in several keywords like:

```
@import   
@media   
@keyframes
```

and others, but I am searching to know what the **@** actually means and how it is used or better yet, how it benefits, change or differentiates from the rest of CSS.

I have read the [W3 section about at-rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#at-rules) but it does not explain clearly (I actually read that and I ended up even more confused) what **@** means and it is specifically used for.

Comment: The `@` is just a marker, like the `#`: an arbitrarily-chosen symbol that means that the following is a keyword for a special rule. Each rule is different, having very little if anything in common.

Comment: Its another "instruction" for the browser parser. Do this because I have this symbol followed by 'X'

Comment: Many thanks @Kolink and Nate for the clear answer. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@charset` at-rule can be used to specify the character encoding of an external style sheet. It must appear before anything else in the file.

`@import` at-rule allows us to import one style sheet into another. All @import at-rules must appear before any rules.

`@media` at-rule lets us target rules to the media types we specify.

`@page` at-rule can be used to specify margins for paged media. You can set different margins for left- and right-hand pages when you’re printing double-sided pages, as well as for the first page.

`@font-face` at-rule allows us to specify custom fonts.

`@namespace` at-rule in CSS3 lets us declare an XML namespace, as well as an optional prefix with which that namespace can be specified.

If I were you I would check out the following links.

**Firstly** : http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/atrulesref

As well as the following:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/At-rule 
http://css-tricks.com/at-rule-css/

Comment: Wow thanks, the link by mozilla and sitepoint clear my doubt about the @ one. Also the user that proposed this question as duplicate is right since the other question has an answer that gave me a hint into how the @ is used. Many thanks.